# How to suppress "using incubating module(s)" compiler warning?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-warnings, java-9, java-http-client

I would like my build to break if any compiler warnings occur, so I enabled `-Werror`. At some point later on I decided to use Java 9 HttpClient which is an incubating module. Unfortunately, I now get the following compiler warning:

```
using incubating module(s): jdk.incubator.httpclient
```

Is there a way to use incubating modules alongside `-Werror` without breaking the build? Ideally, I'd like to suppress this warning showing up altogether.

I am using Maven to build my project, so ideally answers should provide an example of how to get incubation modules to compile as part of a Maven project.

Comment: During the JDK build incubator modules *must be packaged into jmod files* with the `--do-not-resolve-by-default` option of the jmod tool, so that they are not in the default set of root modules for the unnamed module. This makes them, in effect, "opt-in". The `--warn-if-resolved=incubator` option must be also passed to the jmod tool, so that a warning is issued at compile time, link time, and run time if the incubator module is resolved. This warning can be suppressed at compile time, but not at other times.

Comment: @nullpointer I don't think I am using `jmod`. I am compiling my project through maven, so I think only `javac` is getting invoked.

Comment: @nullpointer I still don't fully get it. Are you saying that I have to package my project using the `jmod` tool to suppress this warnings? Are you able to share an example Maven project that does this? (I'll add the Maven tag now)

Comment: This is a known issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187591

Comment: @AlanBateman Would the `-Xlint:-module` not help here temporarily? (Though I agree the cons then might be that the module related warnings would all be disabled). Just a thought since I was unable to find `--should-stop:ifError=PARSE` in the docs.

Comment: @AlanBateman The workaround mentioned in JDK-8187591 does not work in JDK 19. `javac` returns `invalid flag: --should-stop:ifError=PARSE`.